# How can put the ChildBrowser plugin into a panel in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: cordova, touch, extjs, childbrowser

I want to put ChildBrowser into a panel in a Sencha Touch 2 webpage. The first time I used an iframe, but the dimensions were very strange. Now I want to put the Childbrowser plugin into a panel, but I don't know how to do it. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the way ChildBrowser works.  The Sencha Touch stuff lives in your main webview provided by PhoneGap.  ChildBrowser is *another* webview that you can use to display various things on the internet without hijacking your main app's webview.  No way to put one in the other.